# How do I generate surefire report for all tests and make this work with jenkins?

Tags: selenium, maven, jenkins, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a large number of Junit tests running selenium on eclipse, what I would like to do is generate a Junit or surefire report for the tests after all of them are run. I know that with maven you can do this for individual tests by running mvn test on the console and generating a report with:

```
mvn surefire-report:report-only
```

However, this tests and produces a report for each individual test, is there a way to make this work for multiple tests? The reason behind this is because I run these tests headlessly on Jenkins, I know that jenkins email plugin can allow me to pass a html report post build which would give me an idea of test success and failure.

Comment: First selenium tests are integration tests which should be handled by maven-failsafe-plugin. Furthermore if you like to get a report on Jenkins configure Jenkins accordingly ...there is no need to use surefire-report? Or do you create a site within the build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need to have all the right plugins and dependencies in your pom.xml file.

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <!-- `mvn clean test site` to generate the junit html report-->
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
```

Following this add the maven command to your maven build as shown.

[image]

After you run this your IDE will run all the tests in that maven build and generate a surefire.html report which can be found in target/site/surefire-report.html
(You may need to update your maven project to see the folder come up for the first time by right clicking the project, then hover over maven and then click update maven project.)

I would advise doing this as it then works with jenkins when it runs your tests in headless mode which can then be attached to your email extension plugin.

Comment: If you run the test from your IDE you get a report automatically no need to generate an HTML repository via surefire report?...

Comment: You do yes, however, if you are running the tests headless on jenkins and want a report emailed to you then you can fetch the surefire html report in order to send it as part of the email for an easy and clear output of the situation :)

Comment: If you are on Jenkins you should configure that in Jenkins with EMail Template etc. is much easier and faster...

Comment: The jenkins email template is configured however as I stated above I wanted a report to be sent in that email... When you run jenkins the result comes up with a lot of information, it is useful to have a nice well structured report attached to the email. The report provides an easy way to see whats failed and passed.

Comment: I strongly recommend to take a look into https://plugins.jenkins.io/email-ext/

Comment: Like I said in the previous comment, I already have plugins.jenkins.io/email-ext

Comment: Then simply use it....cause the given templates on the docs site already have what you like to do...

Comment: I am using it but it does not come with templates anymore when you click on a template you have to have them on your computer and im not sure where to get such templates.

Comment: The links under "Template Examples" ... ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this command:

#mvn clean test

This will clean the existing reports and run all test cases in one go and generate surefire-reports for all.

Please let me know if this what you are looking for. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I ran it and sadly it only ran 1 of my 2 tests in my playground project, I have multiple unit tests that are part of other packages if that helps? It did actually clear the old report but did not generate a new one. Any ideas?

Comment: You can try #mvn clean test site